# Small Table locking problems with very simple queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a simple table DashboardItem [table columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtOKc.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `DashboardItem` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_dashboard_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `w` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `due_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=178 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I'm running the following queries upon input requests (not that this is in development so there are not a lot of queries running at a time here).

```
DELETE FROM DashboardItem WHERE id = ?

INSERT INTO DashboardItem (client_dashboard_id, x, y, w, h, type, reference_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

UPDATE DashboardItem SET x = ?, y = ?, w = ?, h = ?, type = ?, reference_id = ? WHERE id = ?
```

These are the only queries manipulating this table, but we're getting deadlocks and a whole lot of conflicting Row locks.

We're currently using pooling with the npm library "mysql".

So our queries look like pool.query("Update DashboardItem Se......", [params], callback).

There's very little data in this table (fewer than 100 rows), and all these queries use the where clause on primary key, so I'm really not understanding why we're getting so many lock conflicts and deadlocks here...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a code snippet from the express server using mysql npm library:

```
pool.query(`
    DELETE FROM DashboardItem
    WHERE id = ?
    `, [id], (error, result) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(result);
    });
```

This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow.

Comment: well maybe your connections are never released, or maybe you do not commit your transactions. It would be much better if you also add that code

Comment: I was thinking maybe something along those lines could be going on, but for these simple queries we're not running transactions, it's just auto-committing. I just put the code for our delete query at the end of my question.

Comment: You never released your connections. https://link.medium.com/OjUI5TM8ahb
Take a look at this medium post it is about MySQL with express

Comment: If you check the end of my question you'll see that we are in fact calling connection.release(). Perhaps there's some kind of error happening in the library with connection.release(). I'm adding some massive logging on every single connection that's involved with this table to see if there's ever a connection obtained and not released. I'll let you know what I find, thanks

Comment: Did you create the bug at the MySQL repo? Or You want me to tell you what from you code is making the library crash ?

Answer (score -1):

thank you for all your help.

I found what was happening, and it's really dumb, lol.

Somebody had a connection where they started a transaction that they never committed, then released it back into the pool.

Then, when we requested a connection from the pool, sometimes we'd get the connection with an uncommitted transaction. Because we have auto-commit enabled, when we ran our simple delete or update query we'd expect the auto-commit to go through, but the connection still had an open transaction from the earlier request.

So basically, we'd have a connection with an open transaction locking the table that would never call commit.

Thanks again for the assistance!